# Why would git fetch origin <hash> give non-zero but not an error message?

Tags: git

This was happening:

```
$ git fetch origin 883c5186f0a17190453bfda1bcf1716e7f5fc8e2 && echo "everything is fine"
$ git fetch origin 883c5186f0a17190453bfda1bcf1716e7f5sdfsd
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref 883c5186f0a17190453bfda1bcf1716e7f5sdfsd
```

Then I tried a branch `git fetch origin staging` and then `git fetch origin 883c5186f0a17190453bfda1bcf1716e7f5fc8e2` would return 0. There's no indication about what went wrong, what's the actual issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in [git-config](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-uploadpackallowReachableSHA1InWant):

> **uploadpack.allowTipSHA1InWant**
>
> When uploadpack.hideRefs is in effect, allow upload-pack to accept a
>   fetch request that asks for an object at the tip of a hidden ref (by
>   default, such a request is rejected). See also uploadpack.hideRefs.
>   Even if this is false, a client may be able to steal objects via the
>   techniques described in the "SECURITY" section of the gitnamespaces[7]
>   man page; it’s best to keep private data in a separate repository.
>
> **uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant**
>
> Allow upload-pack to accept a fetch request that asks for an object
>   that is reachable from any ref tip. However, note that calculating
>   object reachability is computationally expensive. Defaults to false.
>   Even if this is false, a client may be able to steal objects via the
>   techniques described in the "SECURITY" section of the gitnamespaces[7]
>   man page; it’s best to keep private data in a separate repository.
>
> **uploadpack.allowAnySHA1InWant**
>
> Allow upload-pack to accept a fetch request that asks for any object
>   at all. Defaults to false.

If you'd like to fetch a specific commit without using any ref, one or more of these variables should be set to true in the remote repository's config. Otherwise, the remote repository would reject the fetch request.

They are false by default and most server-side repositories don't set them to true because of security issues and extra cost to find the commit without a ref. So `git fetch origin 883c5186f0a17190453bfda1bcf1716e7f5fc8e2` fails as the server rejects the fetch request for a specific commit. After you run `git fetch origin staging`, the commit and related objects are downloaded and exist in the local repository, so a following `git fetch origin 883c5186f0a17190453bfda1bcf1716e7f5fc8e2` doesn't have to get them from the remote repository and it's reasonable that it returns no error.